# How does a Docker engine replace a hypervisor and guest OS?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

The left is a VM and rich tis Docker that I got from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBvYlppukUo):

[image]

How can the Docker engine be so light weight that it can replace the Guest OS's and Hypervisor and still work with the Host OS? Essentially it just does a more efficient translation of the different apps and their dependencies than VMs? I heard that the Docker Engine uses the same kernel as the host OS but I'm not sure I understand what that means. Essentially we replaced all the dependencies from multiple Guest OS's and a Hypervisor with one Docker Engine, but I don't understand how that can be done. Does a Docker engine just remove that much extraneous stuff that the Guest OS's shouldn't of ever had in the first place? What is the extraneous stuff that wasn't necessary?

Answer (score 5):

Containers must be understood as a set of isolated processes implemented with Linux kernel primitives such as namespaces and cgroups.  Currently, there are 5 namespaces: PID, mount, network, IPC and user namespaces.  To put it simply: With namespaces, processes cannot see each other unless they are in the same namespace.  Think of it as chroot (kind of a mount namespace) on steroids...  The concept is similar to FreeBSD jails and Solaris Zones. 
 Cgroups are a way to set limits to resource consumption by a group of processes in a namespace.

Docker just implementes Linux containers in their own way, with containers running atop of layers on union filesystems, etc.

Containers run the same kernel as the host.  To reduce the attack surface of the kernel, mechanisms such as seccomp and apparmor/selinux are used to filter a lot of system calls.  In addition, a lot of capabilities are dropped to achieve a level of isolation that makes it difficult to break out of the jail.

Comment: is the docker engine used on the server side or client or both? if so how is it used differently on each side?

Comment: The Docker Engine creates the containers on the server.  The client just interacts with it.  When used on the same host, the docker client interacts with the server through an Unix domain socket.  When on different machines, you may use TLS and authentication for security.

Comment: If you have machine A where you build the code and machine B (server) where you host the code, will they both need to have docker engine installed? would it be correct to say machine A uses Docker to build out images and then pushes them to Docker hub and then machine B pulls the images and then runs them as containers?

Comment: Yes.  Currently, the Docker Engine package contains both the client and server, but the project is being split on multiples levels.  On the binary side, you have runc as client and dockerd/containerd as daemon.  With the Moby Project there are now kits of functionality that we could assemble as legos to achieve what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo's answer is correct in that the Docker engine is really only another process running on the machine that simply configures the kernel with the various namespaces needed to provide isolation of other processes.

I actually just wrote a blog post about this [found here](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2017/05/docker-is-not-a-hypervisor/) talking about this.  In it, I make the argument that a better image would be the one below, which has received great feedback so far. Hopefully it helps to visualize what Ricardo was talking about.

[image: Other container setup]